# Cannot resolve method 'SetDataSource(android.net.Uri)'

Tags: android

Class Code:

```
package com.example.chirag.cook;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class YourMovieActivity extends Activity implements     SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private MediaPlayer mp = null;
//...
SurfaceView mSurfaceView=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    //...
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.bgvideo);

    mp.setDataSource(video);
    mp.prepare();

    //Get the dimensions of the video
    int videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
    int videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

    //Get the width of the screen
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    //Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();

    //Set the width of the SurfaceView to the width of the screen
    lp.width = screenWidth;

    //Set the height of the SurfaceView to match the aspect ratio of the video
    //be sure to cast these as floats otherwise the calculation will likely be 0
    lp.height = (int) (((float)videoHeight / (float)videoWidth) * (float)screenWidth);

    //Commit the layout parameters
    mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    //Start video
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
```

and also, mp.prepare shows me a java.io.IOException. 
This code is to play a video in the background.
mp.setDataSource(video); shows me an error that says "Cannot resolve method 'SetDataSource(android.net.Uri)'"

Comment: you should use mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
     mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder); before SetDataSource method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        holder = mSurfaceView .getHolder();
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.setDisplay(holder);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.bgvideo);
        try{
            mp.setDataSource(this,video);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
```

Comment: But, the other error Cannot resolve method 'SetDataSource(android.net.Uri)' still shows up! Is there any fix for this?

Comment: That error is also resolved. All i had to do was add the context.mp.setDataSource(this, video);

Comment: But, the video still won't play in the background:(

Comment: Try mp.setDataSource(this, video); see my updated answer

Comment: It doesn't show any errors now, but when i run the app on my phone, it shows a black screen in place of the video!

Comment: I believe I have solved the issues you have mentioned in the post :).. if you can provide with some extra info, I could help

Comment: Yes, thank you for that! the 'bgvideo' is a video of about 10 seconds in my 'raw' folder that i want to play in the background of an activity. and the code for that is given above. However, when i run the app on my phone, it shows a black background instead of the video in question. XML Code is as follows:

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/home_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dip" />
    </FrameLayout>